# Rewrite PostgreSQL query using CTE:

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following code to pull records from a daterange in PostgreSQL, it works as intended. The "end date" is determined by the "date" column from the last record, and the "start date" is calculated by subtracting a 7-day interval from the "end date".

```
SELECT date 
FROM files
WHERE daterange((
    (SELECT date FROM files ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1) - interval '7 day')::date, -- "start date"
    (SELECT date FROM files ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1)::date, -- "end date"
    '(]') @> date::date 
ORDER BY date ASC
```

I'm trying to rewrite this query using CTEs, so I can replace those subqueries with values such as end_date and start_date. Is this possible using this method or should I look for other alternatives like variables? I'm still learning SQL.

```
WITH end_date AS 
(
    SELECT date FROM files ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
), 
start_date AS 
(
    SELECT date FROM end_date - INTERVAL '7 day'
) 
SELECT date 
FROM files
WHERE daterange(
    start_date::date, 
    end_date::date, 
    '(]') @> date::date 
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Right now I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-"
LINE 7:     SELECT date FROM end_date - INTERVAL '7 day'
```

Comment: You want the - INTERVAL part to move up into the SELECT clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need two CTEs, it's one just fine, which can be joined to filter data.

```
WITH RECURSIVE files AS (
    SELECT CURRENT_DATE date, 1 some_value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT (date + interval '1 day')::date, some_value + 1 FROM files
    WHERE date < (CURRENT_DATE + interval '1 month')::date
),
dates AS (
    SELECT 
        (MAX(date) - interval '7 day')::date from_date,
        MAX(date) to_date 
    FROM files    
)
SELECT f.* FROM files f
JOIN dates d ON daterange(d.from_date, d.to_date, '(]') @> f.date
```

You even can make it to be a daterange initially in CTE and use it later like this

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT 
        daterange((MAX(date) - interval '7 day')::date, MAX(date), '(]') range
    FROM files    
)
SELECT f.* FROM files f
JOIN dates d ON d.range @> f.date
```

Here the first CTE is used just to generate some data.

It will get all `file` lines for dates in the last week, excluding `from_date` and including `to_date`.

| date | some_value |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-09-26 | 25 |
| 2022-09-27 | 26 |
| 2022-09-28 | 27 |
| 2022-09-29 | 28 |
| 2022-09-30 | 29 |
| 2022-10-01 | 30 |
| 2022-10-02 | 31 |

Answer (score 1):

I ***think*** this is what you want:

```
WITH end_date AS 
(
    SELECT date FROM files ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
), 
start_date AS 
(
    SELECT date  - INTERVAL '7 day' as date
    FROM end_date
) 
SELECT F.date, S.date startDate, E.date endDate
FROM files F
JOIN start_date S on F.date >= S.date
JOIN end_date E on F.date <= E.date
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm not repeating anything, but if I understand your problem correctly I think this will work:

```
with cte as (
  select max (date)::date as max_date from files
)
select date
from files
cross join cte
where date >= max_date - 7
```

Or perhaps even:

```
select date
from files
where date >= (select max (date)::date - 7 from files)
```

Since you have already determined that the CTE has the max date, there is really no need to further bound it with a between, <= or range.  You can simply say anything after that date minus 7 days.

The error in your code above is because you want this:

```
SELECT date - INTERVAL '7 day' as date FROM end_date
```

And not this:

```
SELECT date FROM end_date - INTERVAL '7 day'
```

You are subtracting from the table, which doesn't make sense.